# android app crashes after enabling the app authenticity

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have enabled the basic app authenticity for the mobilefirst based hydrid android app  as per the instruction in 
[enter link description here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/)

But when i run it on the android phone the app crashes. please find the error from the logcat says as follows :

```
03 - 01 18: 44: 57.988 18868 - 18933 / ? E / AndroidRuntime : FATAL EXCEPTION: pool - 5 - thread - 1
Process: com.keycorp.kmf, PID: 18868
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn 't load authjni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.keycorp.kmf-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.keycorp.kmf-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java: 358)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java: 526)
at com.worklight.common.security.AppAuthenticityToken. < init > (AppAuthenticityToken.java: 30)
at com.worklight.wlclient.challengehandler.AuthenticityChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(AuthenticityChallengeHandler.java: 81)
at com.worklight.wlclient.challengehandler.AuthenticityChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(AuthenticityChallengeHandler.java: 32)
at com.worklight.wlclient.api.challengehandler.BaseChallengeHandler.startHandleChallenge(BaseChallengeHandler.java: 71)
at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.checkResponseForChallenges(WLRequest.java: 626)
at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java: 292)
at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java: 52)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 841)
03 - 01 18: 44: 57.998 18868 - 18881 / ? E / com.worklight.common.Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler : Logger$UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException in Logger.java: 452::Uncaught Exception
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn 't load authjni from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.keycorp.kmf-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.keycorp.kmf-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java: 358)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java: 526)
at com.worklight.common.security.AppAuthenticityToken. < init > (AppAuthenticityToken.java: 30)
at com.worklight.wlclient.challengehandler.AuthenticityChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(AuthenticityChallengeHandler.java: 81)
at com.worklight.wlclient.challengehandler.AuthenticityChallengeHandler.handleChallenge(AuthenticityChallengeHandler.java: 32)
at com.worklight.wlclient.api.challengehandler.BaseChallengeHandler.startHandleChallenge(BaseChallengeHandler.java: 71)
at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.checkResponseForChallenges(WLRequest.java: 626)
at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequest.requestFinished(WLRequest.java: 292)
at com.worklight.wlclient.WLRequestSender.run(WLRequestSender.java: 52)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java: 587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java: 841)
03 - 01 18: 46: 07.878 19193 - 19206 / ? D / NONE : establishSSLClientAuth
03 - 01 18: 46: 07.938 19193 - 19206 / ? D / NONE : establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists: false
```

Please help me resolve this issue

Comment: You're missing the native library authjni.  It isn't in your apk.

Comment: How did you build the Android project? Ensure your libs/ folder contains "libauthjni.so" files.

Answer (score 0):

The `libauthjni.so file(s) is part of the default generated Android project.
Make sure that you have not somehow removed these from your project.

[image]